# U-SQL Is it accepted to use more than one FIRST_VALUE to remove duplicates in specific columns?

Tags: sql, u-sql

I have a table where multiple rows are duplicates because of two date columns which  their value are different.

**I want to know if it is accepted to use FIRST_VALUE in both columns like this, to remove duplicate on specified columns:**

```
SELECT
 EmployeeName,
 FIRST_VALUE(StartDateTime) OVER(ORDER BY UpdatedDateTime DESC) AS StartDateTime,
 FIRST_VALUE(UpdatedDateTime) OVER(ORDER BY UpdatedDateTime DESC) AS UpdatedDateTime 
 FROM @Employees;
```

Comment: If that is what you need, then use it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not sure this is the proper manner to remove duplicates on specific columns and want to know the most effective manner to do so.

Comment: If you need to remove duplicates, you need to use `ROW_NUMBER()` over these dates.

Comment: @JohnyL Could you please provide an example as an answer?

Comment: I have answered 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to remove duplicates over some field, you need to use `ROW_NUMBER()` and CTE:

```
-- Sample data: dates duplicates
declare @t table (id int, dt date);
insert into @t values
(1, '2018-01-14'),
(1, '2018-01-14'),
(1, '2018-01-15'),
(1, '2018-01-15');
with cte as (
    select *,
           -- assign row number for each partition consisting of same date
           row_number() over (partition by dt order by dt) as cnt
    from @t
)
-- we're interested only in one row (i.e. first)
select id, dt from cte where cnt = 1;

/*
 Output:
+-------+---------+
| id | dt         |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2018-01-14 |
|----|------------|
|  1 | 2018-01-15 |
+----+------------+
*/
```